# Is there a safe way to unplug Bluetooth adapter in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, adapter, disk-utility

I have wondered about that a lot, is it safe to just unplug the Bluetooth Adapter just like because in Windows we use to have The Safety Remove option and for USB drives or SD card I can unmounted them from Disk Utility and then just unplug them.
thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but I can not really be certain.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct, please click on the grey check box next to it and turn it green. That will help others see the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Safely Remove External Storage

**Such as an USB drive**

With external storage media like USB drive or SD card, the computer (Widnows or Ubuntu) does not write the changes to files immediately. That is, when you copy or modify a file in an USB drive, the computer puts it in a "to do" list and waits until there are enough things "to do" with the USB drive. This is done because it is more efficient to write many small changes at the same time as compared with writing them one at a time when you make them. So, you don't use the safely remove option and just yank out the USB drive out, those changes don't get done and the file may get corrupted.

See more at http://www.howtogeek.com/172931/why-exactly-do-you-need-to-safely-eject-usb-media/

## Bluetooth Dongles Don't Store Data

**They can be yanked out, as long as there is no data transfer going on**

This is not the case with the Bluetooth adapter. For example, if you try to listen to some music using Bluetooth headset and the adapter, the computer can't wait and consolidate the music to be sent to the headset. It has to be done right away. Otherwise you will think your adapter is broken. Similarly, if you use Bluetooth to transfer files between your phone and your computer, it is done right away and when it says the transfer is complete, it is complete. So, I don't see why there should be a safely remove option for Bluetooth adapter.

Also see http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/1/tech-helproom/209172/safely-remove-a-belkin-bluetooth-dongle/

Hope this helps